# jquery why we get not right values?

Tags: jquery

```
$(function () {

    /*
    now we have next lines:
    <div id="cat">
        <a href="#" data-text="category1">category1</a>
        <a href="#" data-text="category2">category2</a>
        <a href="#" data-text="category3">category3</a>
        <a href="#" data-text="category4">category4</a>
    </div>
    */
    var category = $("body").find("#cat a");
    var OdjCategory = {};
    $(category).each(function(category_id,elem) {
        var num = category_id+1;
        $this_category = $(this);
        var timer1 = setTimeout(function(e) {
            $(this).trigger('click');
            var ArrOdjCategory = {
                "CategoryId" : num,
                "Name" : $this_category.attr('data-text')
            };
            OdjCategory[num] = ArrOdjCategory;
            console.log('main array = '+num);
            console.log(OdjCategory);
        }, 1000);
    });     
});
```

if we use function timeout() `timer1`, than we get:

```
{
    1={Object { CategoryId=1, Name="category4"} }
    2={Object { CategoryId=2, Name="category4"} }
    3={Object { CategoryId=3, Name="category4"} }
    4={Object { CategoryId=4, Name="category4"} }
}
```

but it not right and should been:

```
{
    1={Object { CategoryId=1, Name="category1"} }
    2={Object { CategoryId=2, Name="category2"} }
    3={Object { CategoryId=3, Name="category3"} }
    4={Object { CategoryId=4, Name="category4"} }
}
```

Why we get not right values and what we need doing that get right results?

Where error ?

P.S.: if we do not use function timeout() `timer1` we get good results... But we need this fucntion for next actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this_category = $(this);
```

You forgot the `var` keyword.

In your code, `$this_category` is considered to be a global variable, so the last iteration of the loop override the previous values, and all the timer functions access to the same value.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yw1e3dsy/)